# How to make .accurate request for CoreML Segmentation

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

Im working on a bakground removal app , where Im doing the task using this function , but this is not so accurate . I found that Im not requesting accurate output here . I need to implement two line in my function .

Two line :

```
var segmentationRequest = VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest()
segmentationRequest.qualityLevel = . accurate
```

My Function :

```
func removeBackground(image:UIImage) -> UIImage?{
    let resizedImage = image.resized(to: CGSize(width: 513, height: 513))
    if let pixelBuffer = resizedImage.pixelBuffer(width: 
    Int(resizedImage.size.width), height: Int(resizedImage.size.height)){
        if let outputImage = (try? modelCore.prediction(image: 
           pixelBuffer))?.semanticPredictions.image(min: 0, max: 1, axes: (0,0,1)), 
    let outputCIImage = CIImage(image:outputImage){
            if let maskImage = removeWhitePixels(image:outputCIImage), 
    let resizedCIImage = CIImage(image: resizedImage), let compositedImage = 
           composite(image: resizedCIImage, mask: maskImage){
                return UIImage(ciImage: compositedImage).resized(to: CGSize(width: 
                       image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use .accurate Quality level in your request like this
but if you will use .accurate it will take more time to give you proper output. and I geuss the quality can be used only in non-Custom Models .

```
      func generatePhoto(Image: Image?) {
    //generating instance of request
    let request = VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest()
    
    guard
        //Convert Input image to CgImg
        let originalImage = Image?.foregroundImage.cgImage else {
            print("missing require image")
            return
        }
    //Setting quality level
    request.qualityLevel = .accurate
    request.revision = VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequestRevision1
    request.outputPixelFormat = kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8
    
    //Create reqhandler
    let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: originalImage, options: [:])
    do{
        //Process request
        try requestHandler.perform([request])
        guard let mask = request.results?.first else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        //Convert the pixelbuffer to maskImg to get maskImg
        let maskImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: mask.pixelBuffer)
        print(maskImage)
        self.mskImage = maskImage
        
        let foreground = CIImage(cgImage: originalImage).oriented(.up)
        guard let output = blendImages(foreground: foreground, mask: maskImage) else {
            print("Error4")
            return
        }
        //update photoOutput
        print(output)
        //Convert the CIImg to UIImg
         if let photoResult = renderAsUIImage(output){
            print("output",photoResult.size)
            
            self.outputImage = photoResult
            print(outputImage)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Error processing person segmentation request")
    }
   }
```